# 'Animation Nodes' Compared with 'Animation Nodes + Extra Nodes'

Tags: add-on, animation-nodes

What are the main differences between the two Blender addons Nodes 'Animation Nodes' and 'Animation Nodes + Extra Nodes'?

Answer (score 1):

In *Animation nodes + Extra nodes (AN+EN)* - as the name says - there are additional nodes in there. Basically, the *AN+EN* is *AN-fork*, and it has extra nodes as well as extended version of some nodes e.g., *Simulation Nodes, Falloff Tracer, Particles Output, Modified Vector Noise node, Texture Input*, etc. Many of the extra/extended nodes have been merged in *AN* e.g., *Grease Pencil, UV Map, Vertex Color, Custom Attributes, Mesh Points Scatter*, etc. However, there are some nodes which may not be possible add in *AN*.

Comment: Thank you Chris for the answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the differences? Perhaps list the additional nodes or what they do